# What limits bluetooth data transfer speed

Tags: wireless-networking, performance, bluetooth, data-transfer

It's pretty much all in the title, I am trying to figure out important factors in optimizing a bluetooth data transfer.

Specifically my question boils down to the speed difference of different bluetooth versions, ie 4.0, EDR, LE and if the receiving chip plays a big role or not.

Also I am not concerned about physical obstacles, my question is about hardware.

I am working on an embedded device with a Wifi/Bluetooth chip very similar to this on, found [here](https://www.lsr.com/embedded-wireless-modules/wifi-plus-bluetooth-module/tiwi-ble#product-specs). My goal is to send files (apox 7-10MB) between this device and laptops/computers. I have this all set up and I have done a few tests with both a Windows and Mac computer and I've averaged a time of 3 minutes for the full transfer to complete.

From what I have read about BLuetooth 4, EDR, and LE it should be possible to get speeds of approximately 3MBps. Which is what I am looking for (as a minimum), so I am wondering why I am only seeing a fraction of that.

EDIT:
I've calculated the speed I am seeing and it is about 0.08MBps. I am only sending one file to one computer, I have tired several computers on the receiving end, they have always been about a meter or less away and there is no noisy equipment nearby. I have also tired sending files in the other direction but that has failed with very vague error messages such as service not available and error, please try again.

Also I am using the bluez and obexftp packages to transfer the files with the commands

```
hcitool scan    
obexftp -b xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx -p testfile.JPEG
```

Comment: 3MBps is the theoretical max., you're not going to get 3MBps due to real-life/overhead.  What actual speeds are you seeing?  Are you performing the transfers one at time, or are you trying to send to multiple PCs at once?   What have you tried already to rectify/troubleshoot (moved devices, tried different computer, etc.?)

Comment: I've edited the question to address your comment. And I do understand that 3MBps is a best case scenario but what I am seeing is so much lower I think something is wrong somwhere

Comment: Did you find out the answer to this?